# How to prevent entries in the legend overlapping without white space?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm setting the legend with 2 entries.
First, I had a problem that there was white space on the left of the first entry and I added 'width -2' in the 'set key' syntax.
After that, the entries are slightly overlapped. The result is:

[image]

The 'set key' syntax what I used is:

```
set key reverse at screen 0.8, 0.05 spacing 1.5 samplen 2 font ",10"
set key box width 1 vertical maxrows 1
```

What I want is two:

1. Removing the left white space
2. Keeping the gap between the legend entries

Thanks!

== Update ==

I modified the 'set key' syntax with @Ethan Merritt's advise.
However, the left white space still remains like this:

[image]

I want to reduce the left white space in the key box and to adjust the gap between the entries, like this:

[image]

I also update the 'set key' syntax I used above.
Please help me once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"remove the left white space" - to left-justify the text, say `set key Left`.
This will affect all entries in the key box, not just the leftmost one.

"keep the gap between entries" - do not squeeze the box with `width -2`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry but, what you mention is not fit for my intention. With your advise, the result does not remove the left white space in the key box, as you say "This will affect all entries in the key box, not just the leftmost one". How can I remove the white space?

Comment: The width of the columns in the key is determined from the length of the longest title.  By default the titles are right-justified, so all of them except the longest will have whitespace to the left.  If you change to left-justification then all titles will have the same amount whitespace to the left (approx one character width) but will vary in how much space there is between the text and the sample line/point/fill symbol.